# Microsoft SDK in android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, adsi

I want to include Microsoft SDK (ADSI development) files in android. I need to use #include"activeds.h" in .cpp file in my android app. How to include third party lib and header files in android ndk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.  ADSI is a Windows only thing.  It doesn't exist on Linux (which is the base of Android).  It isn't just algorithms, the entire subsystem it relies on doesn't exist, starting with the entire idea of COM.